# How to plot not only the result but also the derivatives of an ode using the ode45 function in Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, matlab

I have already successfully run a code for the simulation of the deflection of beams under different loadings. I used the Matlab program and the ode45 solver for Initial value Problems and bvp4c solver for Boundary conditions. So I generated graphics such as the one below:

[image]

I want now to plot not only the deflection y(x) but also dy/dx and d^2y/dx^2 on the same graphic and I am having difficulties to actually do it. Hope someone can give me a hint. All I want is to plot the function I inserted on the MyFunctionL and MyFunctionNL and it´s derivative together with the result. One of the codes I generated is below:

```
function def1= def1(F,L)
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Deflection 
% F [N] und L [mm]
% EI N*mm^2
% y[mm]
%--------------------------------------------------------------
global Fg Lg EI;
Fg = F;
Lg = L;
Em=200*10^9
```

%This part below is not relevant for the question

```
 for i=1:3
      if i==1
          b=0.055
          h=0.1
          Im=b*h^3/12
      end
      if i==2
          Im=2.5175*10^(-6)
      end
      if i==3
          re=0.065
          ri=0.060
          Im=pi/4*((re^4)-(ri^4))
      end

%As Im is in m^4 we are converting EI to N*mm^2 by multiplying it by (1000^2).    
EI=(Em*Im)*(1000^2)
```

$Now this part below is.

```
%Start point        
x0 = [0 0];
%Längenintervall
xspan = [0 L];
%Call Solver -> Linear
[x y] = ode45(@MyFunctionL,xspan, x0);
%Plot result
figure
plot(x,y(:,1));
if i==1  title('y(x) in a Retangular Profile') 
end
if i==2  title('y(x) in a Iprofile(IPE 100)')  
end
if i==3  title('y(x) in a Round hollow section') 
end
set(gca,'ydir','reverse')
xlabel('[mm]');
ylabel('[mm]');
hold on;
%Call Solver -> NonLinear
[x z] = ode45(@MyFunction,xspan, x0);
%Plot result
plot(x,z(:,1),'-r');
set(gca,'ydir','reverse')
end   
return

%---------------------------------------------------------------
function dy = MyFunctionL(x,y)
global Fg Lg EI;
dy = zeros(2,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = (Fg/EI)*(Lg - x);
return

function dy = MyFunction(x,y)
global Fg Lg EI;
dy = zeros(2,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = (Fg/EI)*(Lg - x)*(1+y(2)^2)^1.5;
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use inaccurate finite difference approximation. You already have an exact expression for your derivatives: the functions `MyFunctionL` and `MyFunction`. You simply need to evaluate them using the `x` and `y` values obtained from numerical integration with [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html). To do this you can either vectorize these functions or wrap them in `for` loops. Additionally, you [should not be using global variables](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/). That's not what they're for and they [slow down your code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115566-why-does-declaring-a-global-variable-take-so-much-time). You should pass additional parameter via an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Here's how you might re-write your two integration functions to vectorize them and not use globals:

```
function dy = MyFunctionL(x,y,Fg,Lg,EI)
dy(1,:) = y(2,:);
dy(2,:) = (Fg/EI)*(Lg-x);

function dy = MyFunction(x,y,Fg,Lg,EI)
dy(1,:) = y(2,:);
dy(2,:) = (Fg/EI)*(Lg-x).*(1+y(2,:).^2).^1.5;
```

You can then call the sub-functions (they could be in separate M-files too), passing in the additional parameters, and obtain the derivatives like this:

```
[x,y] = ode45(@(x,y)MyFunctionL(x,y,Fg,Lg,EI),xspan,x0);
xdot = MyFunctionL(x.',y.',Fg,Lg,EI).';
...
[x,z] = ode45(@(x,y)MyFunction(x,y,Fg,Lg,EI),xspan,x0);
zdot = MyFunctionL(x.',y.',Fg,Lg,EI).';
```

Note the transposes (`.'`) which are present because `ode45` needs a column vector but outputs each time step along the columns (for performance reasons). You could equally write separate functions that use your expressions for the derivates.

Answer (score 1):

In the string

> [x y] = ode45(@MyFunctionL,xspan, x0);

the function ode45 returns not only $y(1)$ (this is your $y(x)$), but also  $y(2)$ (this is you $\frac{dy}{dx}$). Therefore, to plot both of them on the one figure, you just need to write

> plot(x,y);

instead of

> plot(x,y(:,1))).

But note that the value of your derivative is very small in comparison with $y(x)$. (It will be slightly difficult to see - at the top of your plot).

However, the graph of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is a bit more tricky. You need to use some difference approximation, for example like this:

> YY = diff(Y(:,2)) ./ diff(X);
>
> YY(end+1) = 0; %it is the technical string
>
> YY = [Y YY];
>
> plot(X, YY);

Of course, this way maybe not optimal. But at least something.